# upgrade 8.5.15 to 8.9.20 failing

Tags: upgrading

After the upgrade (done via composer) I get the following stack trace:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Field reusable is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 587 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->get('reusable') (Line: 308)
Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent->isReusable() (Line: 68)
Drupal\block_content\BlockContentAccessControlHandler->checkAccess(Object, 'view', Object) (Line: 105)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler->access(Object, 'view', Object, 1) (Line: 709)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->access('view', Object, 1) (Line: 177)
Drupal\block_content\Plugin\Block\BlockContentBlock->blockAccess(Object) (Line: 120)
Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase->access(Object, 1) (Line: 124)
Drupal\block\BlockAccessControlHandler->checkAccess(Object, 'view', Object) (Line: 105)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler->access(Object, 'view', Object, 1) (Line: 370)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->access('view', NULL, 1) (Line: 56)
Drupal\block\BlockRepository->getVisibleBlocksPerRegion(Array) (Line: 137)
Drupal\block\Plugin\DisplayVariant\BlockPageVariant->build() (Line: 259)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Perhaps i need to update db? But I can't:

```
 php -d "disable_functions=" ./vendor/drush/drush/drush updatedb
 [error]  The Pathauto module is not compatible with the current version of Drupal core. Update the <a href="https://drupal.org/project/pathauto">Pathauto</a> module to 8.x-1.6 or later.

 Requirements check reports errors. Do you wish to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 [success] No pending updates.
```

Not sure whether this pathauto is important or not...

Update:
Okay, so let's assume pathauto is really a problem.
I added
"drupal/pathauto": "^1.6"
do composer.json and run composer update.
Something something happened, and now I think i have a pretty new pathauto installed:

```
composer show --all| grep pathauto
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
  drupal/pathauto                          1.10.0   Provides a mechanism for modules to automatically generate aliases for the content they manage.
  ahebrank/pathauto_subnav
  aron-novak/pathauto
  wieni/wmpathauto
  wkse/pathauto
  drupal/pathauto                          1.10.0   Provides a mechanism for modules to automatically generate aliases for the content they manage.
```

But still the same error:
The Pathauto module is not compatible with the current version of Drupal core. Update the Pathauto module to 8.x-1.6 or later.

Comment: This may be this issue from years ago: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2997797

Comment: sounds plausible... when i go to update.php like the link suggests it complains about the same thing - 
Pathauto
The Pathauto module is not compatible with the current version of Drupal core. Update the Pathauto module to 8.x-1.6 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did a bunch of things but mostly what i think worked was:

```
mv modules/pathauto ~/bak
composer require drupal/pathauto:^1.6
cp -r modules/contrib/pathauto/  modules/
```

I am 100% clueless about Drupal so don't ask me why i had to move it out from contrib and whether this is correct.  But seems to work.